# SQL join on returns none values

Tags: sql, mariadb

// EDIT Found the problem. I changed all type from text to varchar. Now it works fine.

I have a table called "sounds" which looks like this:

> **rowID** type int(11) | **userID** type text | **name** type text| **soundfile** type text
>   1 | "mod001:02" | "Jimmy" | "music/song.mp3"

and a table called "soundlist" which looks like this:

> **soundID** type int(11) | **name** type text | **soundfile** type text | **used** type tinyint(1)
>   1 | "topSong" | "music/song.mp3" | 1

My problem is, when i'm run this query

```
SELECT *
FROM sounds
INNER JOIN soundlist
ON STRCMP(soundlist.soundfile, sounds.soundfile) = 0
WHERE STRCMP(sounds.userID, "mod001:02") = 0;
```

i'm getting an empty result!

My goal is to set "soundlist.used" to 0. I only have "sounds.userID" given.
I'm currently using this query:

```
UPDATE soundlist
INNER JOIN sounds
ON STRCMP(sounds.userID, "mod001:02") = 0
SET soundlist.used = 0
WHERE STRCMP(soundlist.soundfile, sounds.soundfile) = 0;
```

Comment: just use update if u want to change the values  from a single table???

Comment: Why dont you JOIN on rowid=soundid

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Mihai 
rowid and soundid arent the same, they're are auto increments.

Comment: @Mureinik
I'm using MariaDB 10.0.13

Comment: Are you [sure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f30c4/1) you have empty set after first query running?

Comment: @zaratustra
Maybe it's because the table use text instead of varchar

Comment: Ok, I guess, it will be good if you provide scripts with your next question.

Comment: @zaratustra
Thanks for your help! I resolved the problem through type chaning.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: This will update sounds.userid to "0" where soundlist.used is "1"

```
UPDATE sounds 
INNER JOIN soundlist ON
    sounds.soundfile = soundlist.soundfile
SET sounds.userid = "0" 
WHERE soundlist.used = "1"
```

If, instead you want the sounds.userid to equal soundlist.us

```
UPDATE sounds 
INNER JOIN soundlist ON
    sounds.soundfile = soundlist.soundfile
SET sounds.userid = soundlist.used
```

Comment: but sounds haven't the field "userid".

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested queries :

```
UPDATE soundlist
    set soundlist.used=0
    where soundfile IN (               -- using IN keyword instead of = if you want to update multiple entries
        select sounds.soundfile
            from sounds
            where sounds.rowID=1       -- or any other condition
    );
```

I am assuming that rowID is an INT.

And if you want to go even further and don't bother comparing strings, why not using foreign keys ?

Let Sounds the same way :

```
rowID | userID      | name    | soundfile
    1 | "mod001:02" | "Jimmy" | "music/song.mp3"
```

And modify sound list to reference sounds :

```
soundID | name      | soundId   | used
      1 | "topSong" | 1         | 1
```

Your query :

```
SELECT *
FROM sounds
INNER JOIN soundlist
ON STRCMP(soundlist.soundfile, sounds.soundfile) = 0
WHERE STRCMP(sounds.userID, "mod001:02") = 0;
```

would become

```
SELECT *
FROM sounds s
INNER JOIN soundlist l
ON s.rowId=l.soundId
where STRCMP(s.userID, "mod001:02") = 0;
```

This saves you one STRCMP.

Consider using indexes on varchar columns used for conditions, it is faster and sometimes easier to read queries (s.userID = "mod001:02" is more straigthforward)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you the `text` data type, if I use `varchar` the first query gets me [the desired result set](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f30c4/1)